# How to get value from core_config_data table and set as default value in config.xml file in magento2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, system-configuration

I want to add value from

```
BLOG > General > Store Information > Store name and set value in General > General > Store Information > Store name
```

which i added.

How it is possible? Please help me...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="abc" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>abc</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="general_tab" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>General</label>
            <tab>abc</tab>
            <resource>abc_Blog::config_blog</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Store Information</label>
                <!-- <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Module Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field> -->
                <field id="display_text" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Store name</label>
                    <!-- <comment>This text will display on the frontend.</comment> -->
                </field>
                <field id="display_text2" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Store name2</label>
                    <!-- <comment>This text will display on the frontend.</comment> -->
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

[image]

Comment: Please share system.xml file of this modules

Comment: see this code... please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need include the `Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface` class consturctor

```
protected $_scopeConfig;

public function __construct(
     ...
     \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface $scopeInterface,
     ...
)
{
    ...
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeInterface;
    ...
}
```

In Your specific place call:

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue('general_tab/general/display_text', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

Comment: $this->scopeConfig->getValue('general_tab/general/display_text', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE); .............. this value i want to stored in "general/store_information/name" using saveConfig() .... how it is possible?

Comment: its solved : => put this below code in observer => execute() function
$showTemplateHint =  $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('general_tab/general/display_text', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
..................................
$this->resourceConfig->saveConfig('general/store_information/name', $showTemplateHint, 'default', 0);

Comment: How can i set use this tab in other store view & store value in 'core_config_data' table ?